# Convert python list to bash array

Tags: python, string, bash, list, loops

I have a python list as a string with the following structure:

```py
var="["127.0.0.1:14550","127.0.0.1:14551"]"
```

I would like to turn the string into a bash array to be able to loop through it with bash:

```sh
for ip in ${var[@]}; do

something

done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  How do you expect a python variable to be used in a bash script?  The two contexts are completely separate.

Comment: That list resembles JSON, have you tried parsing it using a JSON parser? Such as [tag:jq]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Perl to parse the Python output, like so (note single quotes around the string, which contains double quotes inside):

```
array=( $( echo '["127.0.0.1:14550","127.0.0.1:14551"]' | perl -F'[^\d.:]' -lane 'print for grep /./, @F;' ) )
echo ${array[*]}
```

Output:

```
127.0.0.1:14550 127.0.0.1:14551
```

Alternatively, use `jq` as in the answer by *0stone0*, or pipe its output through `xargs`, which removes quotes, like so:

```
array=( $( echo '["127.0.0.1:14550","127.0.0.1:14551"]' | jq -c '.[]' | xargs ) )
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F'[^\d.:]'` : Split into `@F` on any chars other than digit, period, or colon, rather than on whitespace.

`print for grep /./, @F;` : take the line split into array of strings `@F`, select with `grep` only non-empty strings, print one per line.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to treat the string as [json](/questions/tagged/json), and use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to parse it:

```sh
jq -rc '.[]' <<< '["127.0.0.1:14550","127.0.0.1:14551"]' | while read i; do
    echo $i
done
```

> 127.0.0.1:14550
>
> 127.0.0.1:14551